# How Can I solve this problem on Hopf Map?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, hopf-fibration

**I want to solve this**:

Let $\pi : S^3\to S^2$ be the Hopf map. Show that for all $a\in (-1,1)$, the pre-image $\pi ^{-1} (Z_a)\subset S_3$ is the common solution set of the equations $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$, and $|z|^2 - |w|^2 = a$. Use an explicit parametrization of the solution set to conclude that $\pi ^{-1}(Z_a)$ is a 2- torus (i.e. it is $S^1\times S^1$).

Note: Take $Z_a = \{(x_0,x_1,x_2)\in S^2|x_2=a\}$

**Attempt**

The Hopf map is given by:

$$\pi : S^3\to S^2,\quad \pi (z,w) = \frac{1}{|z|^2 + |w|^2} (2\Re(w,\overline{z}),2\Im(w\overline{z}), |z|^2 - |w|^2)$$

Now, we have: $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$ and $|z|^2 - |w|^2 = a$. By adding these equations together, we will get $|z|^2 = \frac{1+a}{2}$. If we let $z = x + iy$, then we will get $$x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1+a}{2}\quad\color{blue}\blacktriangle$$ By subtracting the second equation from the first, and doing the substitution $ w = u + iv$, we will get $$u^2 + v^2 = \frac{1-a}{2}\quad \color{red}\ast$$
By adding $\color{blue}\blacktriangle$ and $\color{red}\ast$ together, we will have:

$$x^2 + y^2 + u^2 + v^2 = 1$$

**Questions:**

This is how far I could get. So:

(1) how does this answer the question, "*for all $a\in (-1,1)$, show that the pre-image $\pi ^{-1} (Z_a)$ is the common solution set of the equations $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$, and $|z|^2 - |w|^2 = a$*"?

(2) how can I use an explicit parametrization of the solution set to conclude that $\pi ^{-1}(Z_a)$ is a$2$-torus (i.e. it is $S^1\times S^1$)?

Comment: You haven't said what $Z_a$ is.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I have edited the question. $Z_a =  \{(x_0,x_1,x_2)\in S^2| x_2 = a\}$

Comment: Why do you write the Hopf-map with factor $\frac{1}{|z|^2 + |w|^2}$? It has value $1$ on $S^3$.

Comment: Your question made me think more about the Hopf circles, and the formulas are prefect for figuring that out. I added some details below, since it is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you answered both questions already?

For (1), you even wrote the conditions out yourself.

For (2), $|z|^2=\frac{1+a}2$ and $|w|^2=\frac{1-a}2$ define two circles and hence the solution set is the product as a 2-torus. (If it is not clear to you yet, $S^3\subset {\mathbb C}^2$ and $z$ and $w$ are the coordinates on them.)

**Let me add a bit more than what the question asks for,** since it is interesting. We can ask for the the inverse image $\pi^{-1}(p_\theta)$ of a point
$$
p_\theta = (\sqrt{1-a^2}\cos\theta, \sqrt{1-a^2}\sin\theta, a)\in Z_a\subset S^2,
$$
where $\theta\in [0, 2\pi]$. Then the condition would be that for $(z, w)\in \pi^{-1}(Z_a)$ with
$$
z = \sqrt{\frac{1+a}2}e^{i\phi},\quad w=\sqrt{\frac{1-a}2}e^{i\psi},
$$
we should have
$$
\phi - \psi = \theta.
$$

Therefore the inverse image of a point is a circle on a torus $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ with coordinates $(\phi, \psi)$ defined by that their difference is a constant.

These are parallel lines with $45^\circ$ angles if you represent your torus by a square. On the torus, they are circles linking with each other. Here is a picture.
[image: Four Hopf circles linking]

Comment: The question actually further asks for an explicit parametrization of the solution, to which I gave $(z(\phi ), w(\psi ))$ as you did above. Although, I didn’t give $p_\theta$, and I hope I am fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

The Hopf map is given by

$$\pi : S^3\to S^2,\quad \pi (z,w) = (2\Re(w\overline{z}),2\Im(w\overline{z}), |z|^2 - |w|^2 ) .$$

Thus for all $a \in [-1,1]$
$$\pi ^{-1}(Z_a) = \{(z,w) \in S^3 \mid|z|^2 - |w|^2 = a\} = \{(z,w) \in \mathbb C^2 \mid|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1, \ z|^2 - |w|^2 = a\} .$$
This shows that $\pi ^{-1} (Z_a)$ is the common solution set of the equations $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$ and $|z|^2 - |w|^2 = a$, where $z, w \in \mathbb C$.

With $z = x + iy$ and $w = u + iv$ you correctly get the equations
$$x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1+a}{2} , \tag{1}$$
$$u^2 + v^2 = \frac{1-a}{2} . \tag{2} $$
For $a = 1$ we get $u = v = 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, thus $$\pi ^{-1}(Z_1) = S^1 \times \{0\}.$$

For $a = -1$ we get $x= y = 0$ and $u^2 + v^2 = 1$, thus $$\pi ^{-1}(Z_{-1}) = \{0\} \times S^1.$$

For $a \in (-1,1)$ both $r_1 = \frac{1+a}{2}$ and $r_2 = \frac{1-a}{2}$ lie in $(0,1)$, thus $(1)$ and $(2)$ desrcibe circles $S^1_{r_1}$ and  $S^1_{r_2}$ with center $0$ and radius $r_1$ and $r_2$, respectively. Hence
$$\pi ^{-1}(Z_a) = S^1_{r_1} \times S^1_{r_2} .$$
This means that $\pi ^{-1}(Z_a)$ is a $2$-torus. It degenerates to a circle for $a = \pm 1$.